# How do I teleport a player (as a named entity) to another named Entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I currently have 2 named armor stands called "In" and "Out". I do

> /execute @e[type=Armor_Stand,name=In] ~ ~ ~ teleport @e[r=2] @e[type=Armor_Stand,name=Out]

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What have you tried to figure out the problem? I would start with the most obvious one: Are the armour stands close to each other? And of course you can try a lot of other things, like modifying the command, finding a minimum example that reproduces the issue and so on.

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean, if I may ask? Does it cause a rainbow sheep storm? probably not, but you get the point. It would be helpful for us to not only know what you expect to happen, but also what happens instead, because that's an indication for us to know what's wrong.

Answer (score -2):

```
/execute as @e[type=Armor_stand,TileEntityData:{CustomName="In"}] tp @p[distance=..2] @e[type=Armor_Stand,TileEntityData:{CustomName="Out"}]
```

I think...